# Linux how to wait for remote pid (telnet)

Tags: linux, shell, telnet, pid

Running a "remote" shell via telnet (no ssh on the remote server), I need to wait for the remote shell end to sending the connection closure i/o "sleep".

. my_local_shell | telnet

```
#!bin/bash
# run remote shell
echo "remote_shell.sh \"required_parameters\""
sleep 30
echo close XX
```

I need rather something like :

```
# run remote shell
echo "remote_shell.sh \"required_parameters\" &"
echo "wait $!"
echo close XX
```

But I could not get it working as I guess the remote pid is "mixed" with the local one.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar sign.

```
echo "wait \$!"
```

or

```
echo 'wait $!'
```

The way you have it now, the special variable gets expanded in the local shell. By escaping it, expansion gets delayed for the remote shell to do.

Comment: thx for this explanation (expansion), I got it working when escaping $ with a single remote process. The point is that the remote shell also run children, waiting for the same pid, and there I'm strugglying. But I'll look further in parent/child pids. I have seen some good doc about this [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/EnglishFrontPage)